# Best way to format data for supervised machine learning ranking predictions

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-modeling, ranking

I'm fairly new to machine learning, but I'm doing my best to learn as much as possible.

I am curious about how predicting athlete performance (runners in particular) in a race of a specific starting lineup. For instance, if RunnerA, RunnerB, RunnerC, and RunnerD are all racing a 400 meter race, I want to best predict whether **RunnerA** will beat **RunnerB** based on past race result information (which I have at my disposal). However, I have many cases where **RunnerA** has never raced against **RunnerB**; yet I do have data showing **RunnerA** has beat **RunnerC** in the past, and **RunnerC** has beat **RunnerB** in the past. This logic extends deeper as well. So, it would seem that **RunnerA** *should* beat **RunnerB**, given this information. My real concern is when it gets more complicated than this as I add more features (multiple runners, different distances, etc), and so I'm turing to ML algorithms to help my predictions.

However, I am having difficulty figuring out how to include this in my row data that I can train (after all, correctly formatting data is 99% of proper machine learning), and I am hoping that someone here might have thought along the same lines in the past and might be able to shed some light.

---

**Example:**

I am currently trying to include **RunnerX**-**RunnerY** past race data by counting all the races that **RunnerX** and **RunnerY** have run together and normalizing them on a scale from `-1` to `1`; `-1` indicating **RunnerX** lost all past races against RunnerY; and `+1` indicating that RunnerX has  won all past races against RunnerY; and `+1` indicating. And `0` indicating an equal number of wins and losses (or no past races against each other).

For instance, if **RunnerA** is racing **RunnerB**, and **RunnerA** has beat **RunnerB** in the past, then I want the algorithm to know that (denoted by a `+1` on the **RunnerB** column of row **RunnerA**); same for vice versa. Taking it another step further, If **RunnerA** is racing **RunnerC** (but the two have never raced each other in the past), and **RunnerA** has beat **RunnerD** in a past race, and **RunnerD** has beat **RunnerC** in a past race, then I want the algorithm to learn that **RunnerA** should beat **RunnerC**. I say *beat* here, but I mean an "average beat" for any **RunnerX**-**RunnerY** combinations when data for more than 1 past race is available.

I have set my data up as:

```
name     track   surface  distance  age    RunnerA   RunnerB   RunnerC   RunnerD
RunnerA  Home    2        400       11     0         1         0         1
RunnerC  Away    2        400       12     0         0         0         -1
RunnerD  Home    2        400       10     0         0         1         0
```

which shows that RunnerA has beat **RunnerB** and **RunnerD** in the past. RunnerC has lost to **RunnerD**. And **RunnerD** has beat **RunnerC**.

---

**The problem:**

The problem is that I don't really think this is a correct display of the information for an ML algorithm.

*From what I understand, ML data should be row independent. And this data isn't because row 1 (**RunnerA**) has beat **RunnerD**, yet the data indicating **RunnerD** has beat **RunnerC** is in row 3.*

Does anyone have any ideas how I might be able to incorporate this past win-percentage-for-runner-pair-combination data??? I'm totally stuck here. I've read a lot about some algorithms that estimate the win loss by simply totaling win statistics, but those don't say anything about the actual probability of a particular runner to beat another particular runner.

Any pointers would be super helpful.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem looks like a lot with the problem of ranking college football teams. I have never worked on this ranking problem, but I believe you can borrow some tools used there to build your model.

Here goes a couple of references:

[Colley Matrix Rankings](http://www.colleyrankings.com/matrate.pdf) - This was one of computer rankings used by the BCS. It is also the only one that shared their methodology.

[An example of the Colley Matrix Rankings](http://public.gettysburg.edu/~cwessell/RankingPage/colley.pdf) - An easy example to follow.

[The Perron-Frobenius Theorem and the Ranking of Football Teams](https://umdrive.memphis.edu/ccrousse/public/MATH%207375/PERRON.pdf) - A well known reference that presents some ranking methods. This paper also shows how to assess the probability of winning a game based on the rankings of the teams.

Comment: These look like great references. Thanks for pointing them out! After a first glance, I think they'll do great to get me started in studying this.